# MySql removing leading and trailing space in a select

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I'm new to querying mysql databases. What I'm trying to do is remove the leading and trailing spaces on the output of a select statement for each column. So far everywhere I looked says to use trim but the examples are updating the table or the select statement is on a string not an actual table. Is there a way to remove these leading and trailing spaces on every column for a select statement?

I basicly need my output to be in csv format but I can't use the output to a file option on the query (different server/permissions issues). I'm trying to sqoop data and format it properly with an eval statement because I'm pulling from two separate tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) string function in MySQL

e.g.

```
SELECT TRIM(column1) AS column1, TRIM(column2) AS column2 ... FROM `table` WHERE ...
```

Comment: I would do the same as Kanes suggested - official documentation is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html for the standard TRIM, LTRIM, and RTRIM MySQL functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried setting it up this way and there is still trailing space. I even tried RTRIM specifically but it didn't help. My query is set up like this: Select TRIM(a.id) as id, TRIM(b.name) as name From tableA a, tableB b where a.value = b.value; That stills leave the extra spaces though.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a regular select statement and doing the parsing after with sed and tr -d.